# TIN to Raster Tool, output elevations are 3.40282e+038 and -3.40282e+038, tried calculate statistics didn't work

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, tin

I have an input TIN file that I created using Create TIN. The elevations are all correct. When I convert the TIN to Raster using the tool, my output elevations are 3.40282e+038 and -3.40282e+038

I've checked projections (and probably do it again) and tried calculating statistics, but so far nothing has changed. Someone else used the same file I was using, output it to the same folder I have been, and they got it to work.

EDIT: I edited out all but the end to file names. My S drive is a server drive.

```py
arcpy.CreateTin_3d("C:/...Default.gdb/water_level","PROJCS['NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Washington_Feet',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983_HARN',DATUM['D_North_American_1983_HARN',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500019.9183995],PARAMETER['False_Northing',100003.9836799],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-92.83333333333333],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',1.000039836799],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',44.74583333333334],UNIT['Foot_US',0.3048006096012192]]","B_XS100 Max_Water Hard_Line <None>;Boundary <None> Hard_Clip <None>","DELAUNAY")

# Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "water_level"
arcpy.TinRaster_3d("water_level","S:/.../water_level_3.tif","FLOAT","LINEAR","CELLSIZE 100.485944","1")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to provide more details of the options you used when first creating the TIN, and then doing the TIN To Raster conversion.  If you re-run both steps and use the Geoprocessing | Results window to Copy As Python Snippet by right-clicking on the tool there you should be able to just edit your Question and paste these in.

Comment: You might double-check your geoprocessing properties for raster data.